# Significant turning points in fractional polynomials

Tags: stata, polynomial, fractional-polynomial

When using fractional polynomial models it has been suggested to use the first derivative of the polynomial function to identify significant periods of change and the second derivative to identify significant turning points. If a fractional polynomial consists of linear components the second derivative is 0. The regression coefficients of linear fractions, as well as an inverse U-shape curve, might be suggesting that there is actually an identifiable peak. How would you find these values of X for which Y reaches its peak, except for just inspecting the graph?

Relevant reference also including Stata syntax:
Lye, J. N., & Hirschberg, J. G. (2012). Inverse Test Confidence Intervals for Turning-Points: A Demonstration with Higher Order Polynomials. Advances in Econometrics, 30, 59.

Example:

I am measuring changes of bone mass over the lifetime using a set of panel data and have identified a fractional polynomial model, as the best fitting one, with three linear components to it which, in Stata, looks like this:

```
fp <Age>, center fp(1 1 1) replace: reg Bone_Mass <Age> i.Sex i.Country1 i.Country2
estimates store eq_1
predict fit1
```

This model presents with an inverse U-shaped curve (bone mass peak around the mid-20s). The regression coefficients suggest increases up to a certain age  and then a decrease (negative regression coefficient for _b[Age_3]). Having extracted sex and country adjusted regression coefficients I fit the first derivative which looks like this:

```
predictnl d1= _b[Age_1]+_b[Age_2]+_b[Age_3], se(d1_se)
*The associated plot
gen t_=1.96
generate up1 = d1 + t_ * d1_se 
generate lw1 = d1 - t_ * d1_se 
line d1 up1 lw1 Age, lwidth( .4 .3 .3) lpattern( "1" "-#-" "-#-") sort , /// 
ylabel(,nogrid) ytitle("1st Derivative Function") legend(off) /// 
name(d1frac, replace)yline(0, lstyle(foreground))
```

The second derivative would be 0.

I am still uncertain as to how exactly to find the age at which the decline starts, i.e. bone mass peaks

Comment: "it has been suggested": By whom and where?

Comment: My mistake, the relevant reference is: Lye, J. N., & Hirschberg, J. G. (2012). Inverse Test Confidence Intervals for Turning-Points: A Demonstration with Higher Order Polynomials. Advances in Econometrics, 30, 59.

Comment: Set the first derivative to 0 and solve for $X$ to find the extrema

Comment: Would you mind elaborating a little bit, based on the example I have added in the original question?